# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't adjust window when switching between external monitor and Retina display

Tags: intellij-idea, multiple-monitors

I have my 15-inch 2017 MacBook Pro connected to an [LG 27-inch 4K monitor](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-27UD88-W-4k-uhd-led-monitor).  When they are connected, I have IntelliJ IDEA showing on the monitor on Desktop 11 (out of the 15 total I have) while Safari and my other stuff shows on the MacBook on Desktop 1. When they are not connected, then I just have IntelliJ showing on the MacBook Retina Display.

I used to have it so that IntelliJ had the size of the various editors and side windows were different depending on whether IntelliJ was being shown on the monitor or the MacBook. Obviously, when showing on the monitor, you have more real estate to work with so you can expand the size of the editors and such so that you can see more text. Now, it used to be that when I would connect/disconnect the MacBook from the monitor, macOS would automatically adjust the size of these windows/editors to the layout that was proportionate to the display it was being shown on. It no longer does this. This is a minor inconvenience that makes me have to readjust the window/editor sizes every time I switch displays.

Originally, I had this layout for when IntelliJ displayed on the LG:

[image: LG my preferred layout]

and this layout for when it was on the MacBook Retina display:

[image: Retina display my preferred layout]

Whenever I would connect/disconnect my MacBook to the LG, macOS would automatically scale IntelliJ so that I didn't have to do anything to make it fit whatever screen it was going to be shown on.

But now, it doesn't do that anymore.

Connecting the MacBook to the LG makes it go from this:

[image: Retina display my preferred layout]

to this:

[image: LG bad layout]

Disconnecting the LG from the MacBook makes it go from this:

[image: LG my preferred layout]

to this:

[image]

What did I do that made macOS no longer automatically scale IntelliJ when switching between displays? What can I do to make it do this behavior again?